# How to deserialize an object that i dont know

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Normally I'm using Newtonsoft to deserialize like this

```
List<myObject> deserializeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myObject>>(mysample);
```

But now, i'm facing a problem where the attribute of mysample can be dynamic which is user define themselves. Thus i cannot use myObject anymore as it is fixed class. So how can i deserialize object like that?

For example the mysample can be something like bellow and etc:

```
[{"Name":"a","Phone":"a","Ic":"a"},{"Name":"b","Phone":"b","Ic":"b"}]
```

OR

```
[{"Id":"a"},{"Id":"b"}]
```

- Target Framework is .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: is the below answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 2):

you can use Dynamic Type

```
List<dynamic> deserializeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(mysample);
```

.NET Framework 3.5 :

```
List<object> deserializeObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(mysample);
```

well you can then use reflection to access value

**sample:**

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = item.GetType().GetProperty("name"); 
String name = (String)(pi.GetValue(item, null));
```

dotnt forget to add using System.Reflection;

Comment: @Xion then use object instead of dynamic

Comment: I have more question please enter [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178719/how-to-deserialize-an-object-that-i-dont-know) to help..

Comment: @ckuri for object yo need reflection.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using dynamic, you can parse the json using JArray

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Thus i cannot use myObject anymore as it is fixed class. So how can i deserialize object like that?

To get rid from this problem `Newtonsoft.Json` have very well feature that we can use

If you don't know which json `object` or `array` comes from your resource. means you can't determine its c# respective object then newtonsoft have `JObject` and `JArray` can handle this problem like

1) Suppose your json string is `object` like

```
var json = @"{ 'Name':'a','Phone':'a','Ic':'a'}";
```

Then you can use `JObject` here

```
JObject jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
```

2) Suppose your json string is `array` like

```
var json1 = @"[{ 'Name':'a','Phone':'a','Ic':'a'},{ 'Name':'b','Phone':'b','Ic':'b'}]";
```

Then you can use `JArray` here

```
JArray jArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json1);
```

After successfully getting `JArray` from your json string. you can also querying on your deserialized object to get particular `object` from it like

```
JObject jObject1 = jArray.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(); 

JObject jObject2 = jArray.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x["Name"] != null && x["Name"].ToString() == "a");

int count = jArray.Children<JObject>().Count();
```

If you want to get certain `key:value` pair from your json then you can get it by below code

```
JProperty jProperty = jObject1.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "Name").FirstOrDefault();
var value = (string)jProperty.Value;
```

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @Xion, view the answer might be it help you :)